# Google Apps Script - Using replaceText to convert date format

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get a batch report with an odd date format of dd.mm.yyy and I would like to automatically be able to convert them all to something google understands is a date, like mm/dd/yyyy. Any help would be awesome. I am a n00b with regex.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var text = doc.editAsText();

 // Change up the date format
 text.replaceText("c?c.c?c.cccc", "/");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could split the date based on the delimiter and then mash them back together how you want with something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  text = '12.03.012'
  textArray = text.split('.')
  text = textArray[0]+'/'+textArray[1]+'/2'+textArray[2]
  Logger.log(text)
}
```

Logging Output shows:
`12/03/2012`

Comment: This would be nice. But would this only work for a date that is exactly '12.03.012'? I think part of the problem is the sheet doesnt know its a date because the first number is DD and it isnt expecting a number greater than 12.

Comment: wait.. that was a dumb question. I can add the cells back up out of order to fix that.. happy friday

Comment: This sort of answer assumes that there is some consistency to your problem. If the date is always of the form 'dd.mm.yyy' then yes this will work for you. if it is a slight variation like 'dd.mm.yyyy', then you could make some modifications to accomidate that, but if it of differing forms (eg. one has `mm.dd.yyy` but others are `dd.mm.yyyy` and others are ...) then you are going to have a hard time tracking it down.

Comment: Exactly :) Happy friday, something else to look into: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp (don't forget to accept an answer if you like it ;)

Comment: Yea, this is definitely going to work for me. Can I tell it to just look at a certain column and use `text = '*.*.*`

Comment: I am having trouble applying this script to a specific column. @bobkingof12vs Can you offer some support? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this: [doc reference.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) you would eventually have some place where you would say `values[row][col].split('.')`

Comment: Maybe a better reference is this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()

Answer (score 0):

I would use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for that. That way you can go directly to a javascript date object, and don't have to mess around with regExps. You can use their [parsing string-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) api to convert your format to standard.

```
var legitDate = moment(oddlyFormatedDate, "MM-DD-YYYY"); // use MM DD etc to describe your odd date format.
```

Comment: This is really cool. Do I need to do anything special to get this to work in a google script?

Comment: I dunno, I've never made a google apps script, but you can probably just link to moment.js